# how fl and fi text are automatically bold on HTML website

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making website on SinglePro html template but somehow fl and fi text in

is bold automatically. 
There is not any problem with the code.
URL:

Comment: which text are you saying exactly

Comment: You may have a <span class> defined for this and a property set to it to make it bold, or just some kind of class/id ? The image you gave doesn't show the code or anything so it's a bit hard to find the solution.

Comment: Post code if you want to know why :D

Comment: The chars are not the "real" chars. You are using `ﬁ` and `ﬂ` instead of `fi` and `fl`.

Answer (score 2):

Its just a typing error,
try this

```
<p>These unlimited designs are provided for a flat monthly fee.</p>
```

Comment: i have used the same thing but "fl" in "flat" is bold, if you look at the source code of the url i have given. Its a simple paragraph but showing fl and fi in bold.

Comment: Okay i got this that was an typing error thanks for the help.